# SocialEngine hook does not work

Tags: hook, webhooks, socialengine

I have created a new module to add a new step to the signup process to get the user's phone number. Everything works fine, except the fact that after the signup, I need to grab the phone number I have received in my specific step and add it to the users table. For this purpose, I have added a hook in my module's manifest file as follows to be triggered after signup completes:

```
<?php

return array(
    'package' =>
    array(
        'type' => 'module',
        'name' => 'advancedsmsplugin',
        'version' => '4.0.0',
        'sku' => 'com.company.sms',
        'path' => 'application/modules/Advancedsmsplugin',
        'title' => 'Advanced SMS Plugin',
        'description' => 'Advanced SMS Plugin',
        'author' => 'Company Ltd.',
        'callback' =>
        array(
            'class' => 'Engine_Package_Installer_Module',
        ),
        'actions' =>
        array(
            0 => 'install',
            1 => 'upgrade',
            2 => 'refresh',
            3 => 'enable',
            4 => 'disable',
        ),
        'directories' =>
        array(
            0 => 'application/modules/Advancedsmsplugin',
        ),
        'files' =>
        array(
            0 => 'application/languages/en/advancedsmsplugin.csv',
            1 => 'application/modules/User/Form/Signup/Phone.php',
            2 => 'application/modules/User/Plugin/Signup/Phone.php',
        ),
    ),
    'hooks' => array(
        array(
            'event' => 'onUserCreateAfter',
            'resource' => 'User_Plugin_Phone',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

I have also created the class that I named in the hook namely `User_Plugin_Phone` and saved it as `application/modules/user/Plugin/Phone.php`.

```
class User_Plugin_Phone  extends Core_Plugin_Abstract {

    public function onUserCreateAfter($event) {
        echo '<script>console.log("Inside User_Plugin_Phone::onUserCreateAfter");</script>';

        echo '<script>alert("Inside User_Plugin_Phone: onUserCreateAfter");</script>';

        $payload = $event->getPayload();
    }

}
```

But, logs show that the hook is not triggered at all. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001975/how-to-change-core-module-files-in-socialengine4/23924862#23924862) and [this](https://www.tmdhosting.com/kb/question/how-to-create-a-hook-in-socialengine-for-friends-list-update/), and I think I have followed them correctly. Any ideas why this does not work]?

Comment: It should work. Please add zend log.

Comment: It does not work. How should I write logs in Zend? Where are those logs written?

Comment: $log = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Log'); $log->log("Region could not be found, contact admin: " . $region, Zend_Log::ERR); check your log in temporary/log/main.log

Comment: @GauravSharma thank you very much. This helped me see that the hook was indeed invoked. But, other logging methods like JS don't. Why?       `$log = Zend_REgistry::get('Zend_Log');
      $log->log('User_Plugin_Test->onUserCreateAfter', Zend_Log::ERR);
      echo '<script>alert("User_Plugin_Test->onUserCreateAfter");</script>';`